# Add text to textarea - Jquery

Tags: jquery, text, html, addition

How can I add text from a DIV to a textarea?

I have this now:

```
    $('.oquote').click(function() { 
      $('#replyBox').slideDown('slow', function() {
      var quote = $('.container').text();   
         $('#replyBox').val($('#replyBox').val()+quote);   
        // Animation complete.
      });    
    });
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Just `append()` the text nodes:

```
$('#replyBox').append(quote);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nQErc/

Comment: This doesn't add the text in the textarea, but outside of it.

Comment: No it doesn't :) Look at the code and inspect the element. You might be thinking of `after()`

Comment: Although: It add the text, but it creates many spaces. How can this be avoided?

Comment: Hmm. Not that good with jQuery. I tried this:
$('#texta').append($(jQuery.trim('#reply<?php echo $forumPost['post_id']; ?>')).text())

But it did not work.

Comment: What are the values of both nodes before one is appended to the other?

Comment: Use .val() not .append() or you'll face issues.

Comment: @ermenkoff is very right. I had cases where `.append()` worked and others where it was simply ignored for no obvious reason. The answer of Felix Kling using `.val()` is stable and should be preferred!

Comment: `append()` only works if you did not change the content of the textarea befor (e.g. by typing)!!

Comment: It won't work when the textarea is already edited. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722914/jquery-append-not-appending-to-textarea-after-text-edited

Comment: I had to use `.text()` instead of `.val()` otherwise it just kept appending even though I had reset the contents completely.

Answer (score 54):

That should work. Better if you pass a function to `val`:

```
$('#replyBox').val(function(i, text) {
    return text + quote;
});
```

This way you avoid searching the element and calling `val` twice.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Better than `$('#replyBox').val($('#replyBox').val()+quote);` because it does not search the element and call `val` twice.