# Append text to the end of textarea using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm trying to append text at the end of a textarea using jquery.

my html code looks like this:

```
<textarea class='form-control' placeholder="Write something..." id="message" name="message" size='20'></textarea>
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="deptList">
      <label for="departments" id="deptList">Select a department
        <small>use this in case you've set up your account to <a
                                                href="#"> include a department</a> at the end
                                            of the text
                                        </small>
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="" class="checkbox-inline" id="deptCheck">
      <select class="form-control" id="departments">
        <option>Dept. 1</option>
        <option>Dept. 2</option>
        <option>Dept. 3</option>
        <option>Dept. 4</option>
        <option>Dept. 5</option>
        <option>Dept. 6</option>
        <option>Dept. 7</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>

</fieldset>
```

and my script to append the text is:

```
$('#deptCheck').click(function() {
    var theMessage = $("#message").text();
    var theDepartment = $("#departments").find(":selected").text();

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

        console.log(theMessage + theDepartment);
        $("#message").val(theMessage + theDepartment);
    }else {
        alert('you have included department in your text, please remove it to avoid extra charges');
    }
});
```

so far:
- I can add the value of the drop down option to the text area BUT when I add it, it clears all the existing text.

Wha I want to achieve is that a user types some text in the text area, the user then selects an option from the dropdown under the text area and then, the text of the dropdown is added at the end of the typed text in the text area. I have tried from material online but I seem not to get it right. Where I'm I going wrong?

here is a link to a fiddle of the same [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/musale/h2dp1oqu/6/)

Comment: **[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/h2dp1oqu/9/)**?

Comment: Previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058864/add-text-to-textarea-jquery

Answer (score 8):

To get the `text` inside a `textarea` you have to use the `val()` function:
`$("#message").val();`

```
$('#deptCheck').click(function() {

  var theMessage = $("#message").val();
  var theDepartment = $("#departments").find(":selected").text();

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

    console.log(theMessage + theDepartment);
    $("#message").val(theMessage + theDepartment);
  } else {
    alert('you have included department in your text, please remove it to avoid extra charges') //disable input
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/h2dp1oqu/8/

Comment: That's what I needed @Cristy Thank you mate!

Comment: @falcon No problem. This was a bug that was really easy to catch if you would have debugged your code. If you used `console.log(theMessage)` after getting the text from the `textarea`, you would have seen that the value was not correct. After that, you would have traced that the problem comes from the `.text()` function not returning the correct value. And if you searched on Google "get text from textarea jQuery" you would have found the correct function to use, `.val()`.

Comment: Also, you might want to read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8854317/407650

Comment: I used console to debug and it displayed the text for the options but nothing was displayed for the textarea. And I sure did try using val() but I guess I mixed up things along the way and got stuck. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your two first lines with

```
var theMessage = $("#message").val();
var theDepartment = $("#departments").val();
```