# Insert data in textarea on change input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code and is running well but when i delete some character from textarea it stop working!!!

```js
$(function() {
  $('#inputnumserie').keyup(function() {
    var numserie = $(this).val();
    $('#test2').append($('#inputnumserie').val())
    $('#inputnumserie').val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="inputnumserie" id="inputnumserie" style="text-align:right;" size="14">
<textarea id="test2"></textarea>
```

Comment: I really dont get your question. Can you provide an example output.

Comment: @NewbeeDev check the snippet --- write on input / then delete some from textarea / write again on input

Comment: Its better see here http://jsfiddle.net/pedrocordeiro/nQErc/704/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `append` you are just inserting nodes inside the textarea and seems like a buggy approach, when your issue happens the text doesn't show but it's still inserted on the DOM -- Check with inspector tools --- .

The solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7058930/2887133), could be update the `val()` of the textarea instead of append nodes.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#inputnumserie').keyup(function() {
    var numserie = $(this).val();
    $('#test2').val(function(i,text) {
      return text + numserie;
    });
    $('#inputnumserie').val('');
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  display:block;
  width:80%;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="inputnumserie" id="inputnumserie" style="text-align:right;" size="14">
<textarea id="test2"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('#inputnumserie').on("input",function(){

         var txt = $("#test2").val() + $(this).val();
         $("#test2").val(txt);

         $(this).val("");

     })


})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        
        <input type="text" name="inputnumserie" id="inputnumserie" style="text-align:right;" size="14">
<textarea id="test2"></textarea>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script>
           
           
    $(document).ready(function(){

         $('#inputnumserie').on("input",function(){

             var txt = $("#test2").val() + $(this).val();
             $("#test2").val(txt);

             $(this).val("");

         })


    })
        
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```