# Is it possible to include for text box comma separated values in span tag

Tags: html, css

I am working on `in place edit` functionality in which, in which a user can enter values as comma separated but I have to put style on those each comma separated values which is not possible as all values are in one textbox, is it possible to put each entered values in a span tag with a class name so that I can apply `CSS` or hide the textbox and show the styled span tag .
[image: UI for user entered values]

I am doing something like this 
[image]

How to take those values and put it in the span/div tags so that I can apply CSS for styling or any other method for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery to edit the text box without typing. You need append.
[Add text to textarea - Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058864/add-text-to-textarea-jquery?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

You could not use the tag(span) inside the text input type. You can use styling to apply the css.

Try the below method.

```
<div class="selected_values">
      <span class="grey">val1</span>
      <span class="grey">val2</span>
      <span class="grey">val3</span>
      <span class="grey">val4</span>
    </div>


.selected_values {
      width: 400px;
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .selected_values .grey {
      display: inline-block;
      background: grey;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 10px;
      width: 120px;
    }
```