# Add text to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to add text "username" to `textarea` when some event is occurred, and this code works

```
$("textarea").append("username")
```

Exactly until I add some text to that `textarea` manually. How to avoid this behavior?
This is what I have on html source.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:add_to_textarea('User')">User</a>
```

Comment: set us up an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery .append not appending to textarea after text edited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722914/jquery-append-not-appending-to-textarea-after-text-edited)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$("textarea").val($("textarea").val() + "username");`

Answer (score 2):

`.val()` perhaps?  If you're trying to stick the value into the textarea box.  Not sure what append actually does.

Comment: no that will set the entire value of the textarea.  he wants to add to the existing

Answer (score 2):

Don't change the HTML/DOM of the textarea, but its value property (`.val()` in jQuery). This is a bit hackish, because a html `<textarea>` is only allowed to contain character data, just like a `<input>`s value attribute - though you code the text between the tags.

So if you want to add something, use

```
$("textarea").val(function(prev){ return prev+" "+username; });
```