# using javascript display the multiple selected td values

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using java-script function when i click a td the value is stored in a variable and display in a textarea its works good. but when i click another td value in the textarea changed to new one.

I am using java script for creating table and with javascript itself i generate the id

```
 str += "<td id='R" + i + "C" + j"'>Demo</td>";
```

Here my code execute when click is triggered

```
      $(this).addClass('active');
      var id = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
      document.getElementById('hit').value += id; //hit- id of textarea
```

is it any way for append the values one by one when user clicks multiple td

Comment: use `$("#hit").val($("#hit").val() + id);` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722914/jquery-append-not-appending-to-textarea-after-text-edited

Comment: Your code works fine. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyhzB/). Please add more details into your question (edit the question instead of commenting), or create a jsFiddle yourself that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if i grasped your question clearly but if you want to append to the textarea the value of the td clicked instead of replacing it you can do something like this:

```
 $("td").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');  //i let this but i don't get what you need it for
    $('#hit').val($('#hit').val()+$(this).text());
});
```

if you want to store the value of the td you can just put an additional :
var value = $(this).text();

Answer (score 1):

I've created a fiddle which hopefully is what you are looking for.

```
$('#tbl td').click(function() {
    $('#txta').val($('#txta').val() + $(this).text());
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B8fqK/2/

Comment: Please always post the important parts of your code on SO as well.