# JQuery function won't fill textarea after it is edited

Tags: php, jquery

I have an issue with a textarea which is filled dynamically out of a database by userinput.

All works fine, but as soon as the content of the textarea is edited, it won't update itself after the next function call.

I already stumbled over this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722914/jquery-append-not-appending-to-textarea-after-text-edited), which is telling me that i should use the val() method. I did, but it did not work.
I also tried to set the function asynchronous to prevent my clear() function from being executed just after the textarea was filled by php, but also, not working.

Here is my Code:

[HTML / JS](http://pastebin.com/efTp0Wgi)

[PHP](http://pastebin.com/BwMR8G2v)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can Put the above comment as answer, and Accept your own Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it... .text() instead of .val() ...

```
            function copyToArea(){

                var content = $('p#resultpara').text() ;
                $('textarea#editarea').val(content) ;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you should try

```
$('textarea#resultpara').val("") ;
```

Comment: Hell...it was caused by a non-capital 'S' in "beforeSubmit". Clear works now, but it won't fill the textarea at all. Anyways, i'm a little closer to my target, thank you.