# Appending values to textarea with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append the value from dropdown to textarea, This is working, I can add value but when I make changes on textarea, I can't add anymore when I edit the text area..

```
$('#addWord').click(function() {
   $('#textarea').append($('#selectbox').val() + ", ");
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery .append not appending to textarea after text edited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722914/jquery-append-not-appending-to-textarea-after-text-edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it using `.text()` instead of `.append()`

```
$('#addWord').click(function() {
   $('#textarea').text($('#selectbox').val() + ", ");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat a textarea like any other input and use val()

```
$('#addWord').click(function() {
   $('#textarea').val($('#textarea').val()+" "+$('#selectbox').val());
});
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/BwV9F/

Comment: This is incorrect. A textarea doesn't have a value attribute.

Comment: @NeilCresswell See working example I added to answer

Comment: my apologies. You're correct and this does work. I seem to remember that at some point it did not, but I could be wrong. +1-ing.