# jQuery append do not work after edit textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea with pre-filled text and two buttons to append (multiple times) some values by click.

That works only fine if the textarea was not clicked or edited before. I need to use append, .val or .html will replace the pre-filled text.

```
$('#upload111').change(function() {
    var names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) {
        names.push($(this).get(0).files[i].name+'\n');
    }

    $('#filesinfoarea').append("\n"+names); 

});

</script>
<script>

$('#getpath').click(function(){
    var id = $( "#p_company option:selected" ).text();
    var direc1 = 
    $("input[name='direction']:checked").parent('label').text();

    if ($('input[name=direction]:checked').val() == "1") {
        var direc = "Datenein";
    }
    if ($('input[name=direction]:checked').val() == "2") {
        var direc = "Datenaus";
    }

    var date = new Date().toISOString().replace('-', '').split('T') 
     [0].replace('-', '');

     $('#filesinformations').find("textarea").each(function(){ 
        $(this)
            .append("\n")
            .append("X:\\Test\\"+direc+"\\"+id +"\\"+ date+"\\*.*")
    }); 

    });

</script>
```

Comment: You can only use `.val()` to change the text of a text area.  So you need to use something like `$("textarea").val($("textarea").val() + "\n" + "Test");`  (other variants are available https://api.jquery.com/val/)  `$("textarea").val(function (i, val) { return val + "\n" + "Test" });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending values to textarea with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225054/appending-values-to-textarea-with-jquery)