# After erasing/clearing a textarea I can no longer append text to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a tool to help me assemble different keyword combinations for AdWords. I have a simple form with three checkboxes, an input box (for the starting keyword), a submit button and a textarea for the results (the variations on the input).

The first time around it works great, my conditionals are all working and I can run off a series of keywords that, on each `.submit()`, will populate the textarea. The problem comes when I erase the contents. Here is an example of how it is populated:

```
if($("#phrase").is(":checked")) {
    //Get keywords from input
    var text = $("#keyword").val();

    //Prepend and append double-quotes
    text = "\"" + text + "\"";

    //Output
    var val = $("#output").val();
    $("#output").append(text + "\r\n");
}
```

When I submit, I know it's still executing somewhere in my `.submit()` function because if I uncheck all of the boxes my `alert` (not shown) gets thrown.

Thinking it was something I was missing in the logic of my reset, I removed the reset entirely and posted it to my personal site so I could start working. I ran off some keywords, then manually deleted the contents of the textbox. Strangely, the same thing is still happening: after erasing/clearing the textbox, I can't get it to take the keyword and create any more variations!

I have created a fiddle here: [Keyword Variations Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gYFP3/1/) -- I'm able to recreate the issue and have no idea why it's happening. Try deleting the text after you've generated a few keywords and then try to generate a few more.

Comment: You should be using `.val()` to modify the value of a `textarea`, not `.append()`.

Comment: Please post the code that updates the textarea in your question, since that's where the problem is, not in the reset code.

Comment: @Barmar - the entire code block is in the fiddle as it is too cumbersome to post.

Comment: I've updated my fiddle with Kyle's answer but am still unable to populate the textarea after clearing it. http://jsfiddle.net/gYFP3/3/

Comment: Please post your code here, not just on the fiddle.

Comment: I have updated the code sample for future readers. Thanks @Barmar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting issue. I was concerned about your use of `append` on the textarea since I remembered hearing that textareas were more like text inputs than divs so I tried using `val` instead, and it worked fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/gYFP3/4/

And here's the relevant code.

```
//Output
var $output = $("#output");
var val = $output.val();
$output.val(val + text + "\n");
```

Comment: Kyle is right and you can refer to this answer for a little more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4723017/2754848. Append is better for HTML elements and nodes. Val should be used for form items.

Comment: Hmm. I just edited the fiddle and still cannot get the keyword to write to the `textarea` after I've manually cleared it by selecting all contents and deleting. http://jsfiddle.net/gYFP3/3/

Comment: Sorry, that did in fact work. I hadn't updated a portion of my code.

Comment: @Kyle Where is that code in your fiddle? Did you post the correct link?

Comment: Kyle's solution was correct; I hadn't updated a portion of my code and so still had appends in there. `.val()` is working.

Comment: @Barmar updated. apparently i don't know how to save fiddles.