# How to add text in textarea using jquery without removing previous text

Tags: html

How to add text in textarea using jquery without removing previous text.

```
    $('.btn-uservar').on('click', function (){             

         var insertText = $('#uservar').val();                           
         $('#template').append(" "+insertText);

    });
```

But it only works for first time.when i click again it does nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use val to append the value of the textarea instead of append.

```
$('#template').val($('#template').val() + " "+insertText);
```

Inside the dom the value and text attributes of textarea tags are stored separately. When you use append the text is appended but the value is blanked because it is no longer consistent with the text. I believe your second call to $('#temnplate').va() is returning the blanked value, not the appended text.

See the answer in this link, it explains the problem well.
[append not appending to textarea after text edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722914/jquery-append-not-appending-to-textarea-after-text-edited)

Answer (score 1):

Create it as a function instead. I have had this issue with AJAX where it only works once, this seemed to fix it. Create both old and new as variables and then concatenate them.

```
$('.btn-uservar').click(function(){
  appendText();
}


function appendText(){
    var textareaText = $('textarea').val();
    var insertText = $('#uservar').val();
    $('textarea').val(textareaText + insertText);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-uservar').on('click', function () {
        $('textarea').append(" ").append($('#uservar').val());
    });
});
```