# Append new line of text without using ".append"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown that has `contacts` in there, i.e. `John`, `Bob`,  etc. and a button next to it that when it's clicked, it will display the contact's phone number in my `<textarea></textarea>`.

Each time when I pick a contact and press the button, I want to display the number in my textarea and each additional contact's number I add I want the number to display below the previous number. So basically I need a line break between each number like this.

`1234567890`

`5557778888`

When I use my first function using `.append`, it works the way I want however, if I edit the numbers or take out numbers, I can't use my button to add numbers to the textarea anymore. I realized from [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722914/jquery-append-not-appending-to-textarea-after-text-edited/4723017#4723017) that it's because the text nodes and the value can be disconnected.

Then I tried using `.val`, however this just replaces the numbers in my textarea instead of appending below it.

What would be the best way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Let me know if you need any additional information.

My javascript functions:

Using `.append()`

```
    selectOption: function() {

        $('#addContact').click(function() {
            $('#toPhoneNumber').append($('#toAdd option:selected').data('number') + '&#xA;');

        });

    },
```

Using `.val()`

```
    selectOption: function() {

        $('#addContact').click(function() {
            $('#toPhoneNumber').val($('#toAdd option:selected').data('number') + '\n');

        });

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nums =[];
.
.
selectOption: function() {
  $('#addContact').click(function() {
    var num =$('#toAdd option:selected').data('number'); 
    if (nums.indexOf(num)==-1) nums.push(num);
    $('#toPhoneNumber').val(nums.join( '\n'));
  });
},
```

Comment: Just what I am looking for! Just a quick question, what's a good way to prevent adding the same contact's number more than twice? Currently, I can click the button multiple times and it will add that contact's number multiple times in my textarea, which is not what I want. I apologize for asking another question here, you don't have to answer it. Appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that with this, I won't be able to manually input numbers in the textarea as this will not save the numbers I manually typed in.

Comment: @user3128376 please see update for the dupe. If you want to type yourself, add `nums=$("#toPhoneNumber").val().split("\n");` perhaps with a test to see there are any numbers in the field before using nums

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I tried your updated version but now it's not displaying anything at all in the textarea.

Comment: Sorry I am on my phone so I cannot test. Look in the console. I likely missed a bracket

Comment: Nevermind, I made a mistake. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: You may need to filter the array since you can now type a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

With val you can try:

```
selectOption: function() {
        var temp = $('#toPhoneNumber').val();
        $('#addContact').click(function() {
            $('#toPhoneNumber').val(temp + $('#toAdd option:selected').data('number') + '\n');

        });

    },
```