# Javascript can't run twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[You can see the app there](http://link-tags.com/adgen/index.html)

I have i piece of javascript function generating data.
I use var in inputs, then i parse them.
When i hit the "generate button" all is ok, my textarea is populated with my data and vars are parsed.
Then, if i choose to delete data inside the result textarea, changing my vars in my inputs to create a different variation of report and i hit again the generate button , nothing happend...

Try to add data, generate report, delete data into the result textarea, then regenerate a report... (sources are in clear on website (JS, HTML)

[You can see the app there](http://link-tags.com/adgen/index.html)

Thanks a lot for your helps :)

JS CODE :

```
    /**
 * Parse a template with data
 * 
 * @param {String} tpl
 * @param {Object} data
 * @returns {String}
 */
var parseStr = function (tpl, data) {
    return tpl.replace(/\{\{([\w\.]*)\}\}/g, function (str, key) {
        var keys = key.split('.');
        var v = data[keys.shift()];
        var l = keys.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            v = v[keys[i]];
        }
        return typeof v !== 'undefined' && v !== null ? v : '';
    });
};

/**
 * Array to csv string
 * 
 * @param {Array} ary
 * @returns {String}
 */
var ary2csv = function (ary) {
    var l = ary.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        ary[i] = ary[i].replace(/"/g, '""');
    }
    return '"' + ary.join('","') + '"' + "\n"
};

/**
 * Add new variable
 */
$('#addVar').on('click', function () {
    var nRows = $('#vars > .row').length;
    var $new = $('#templates .row').clone();
    $new.find('label').attr('for', 'VAR' + nRows).text('{{' + 'VAR' + nRows + '}}');
    $new.find('input').attr('id', 'VAR' + nRows);
    $new.appendTo('#vars');
});

$(document).on('keyup', '.var', function () {
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
    $row.find('.col-xs-4').text('' + len);
    if (len > 35) {
        $row.css('color', 'red');
    }
    else {
        $row.css('color', '');
    }
});

/**
 * Add new group
 */
$('#addGroup').on('click', function () {
    var $new = $('#groups .group:first').clone();
    $new.find('input').val('');
    $new.appendTo('#groups');
});

/**
 * Build the report
 */
$('#make').on('click', function () {

// Variables dynamiques
    var zones = {};
    var nRows = null;
    var isValid = true;
    $('#zones textarea').each(function () {
        var ary = $(this).val().split("\n");
        zones[$(this).attr('id')] = ary;
        if (nRows === null) {
            nRows = ary.length;
        }
        else if (ary.length !== nRows) {
            isValid = false;
            return;
        }
    });
    if (!isValid) {
       alert('Chaque zone de texte doit contenir le même nombre de lignes (vides ou non vides).');


        return;
    }

// Variables fixes
    var data = {};
    $('#vars input').each(function () {
        data[$(this).attr('id')] = $.trim($(this).val());
    });
    // Clear report
    $('#report').empty();
    // Columns name
    var titles = [];
    $('#groups .group:first label').each(function () {
        titles.push($(this).text());
    });
    $('#report').append(ary2csv(titles));
    // On boucle sur le nombre de ligne dans les zones
    for (var i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {

// On ajoute a data chaque zone pour la ligne i
        for (var j in zones) {
            data[j] = zones[j][i];
        }

// On parse chaque texte
        $('#groups .group').each(function () {
            var cols = [];
            $(this).find('input').each(function () {
                cols.push(parseStr($(this).val(), data));
            });
            $('#report').append(ary2csv(cols));
        });
    }
});
```

HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="fr" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="author" content="Cédric Duma">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>Mass AdText Generator</title>

        <!-- main JS libs -->
        <script src="assets/js/libs/modernizr.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/libs/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Style CSS -->
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- General Scripts -->
        <script src="assets/js/general.js"></script>

        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <!--[if gte IE 9]>
        <style type="text/css">
            .gradient {filter: none !important;}
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="assets/css/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="assets/js/video.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body class="body-wrap">
        <!--container-->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1>Générateur en masse de textes d'annonce</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="assets/images/baseline.png" alt="Mass AdText Generator" class="img-responsive">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <p class="text-justify">Vous avez la charge de <b>créer des annonces pour vos campagnes AdWords</b>, et cette tâche peut vite devenir <b>très cronophage</b>. Lorsque vous cumulez un important nombre de campagnes et/ou de groupes d'annonces et que vous souhaitez écrire 3 annonces à chaque fois, vous vous embarquez pour quelques heures de travail.<br/>
                                        <br/><b>Créez automatiquement des centaines d'annonces</b> rapidement et cela en quelques clics grâce à cette application simple d'utilisation ! Il vous suffit de préparer en amont quelques informations pour remplir les différentes zones de textes.<br/><br/>Remplacez ensuite le contenu des variantes de textes d'annonces avec vos variables, cliquer sur le bouton "Générer le rapport" et voila ! Il ne vous reste plus qu'à utiliser Excel pour convertir ces données au format CSV pour les intégrer dans AdWords Editor par exemple.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
                                    <!-- <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <br/>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2>Première étape : Listez vos groupes d'annonces ainsi que les textes spécifiques.</h2>
                        <small>Définissez vos noms de groupes d'annonces, Lignes de description, Url finale ou tout autre texte spécifique.</small>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <br/>
        <section>
            <div class='container'>
                <p class="alert alert-warning">Il est important que chaque zone de texte comporte le même nombre de lignes pour que la génération soit possible.
                    <br/>Il est possible d'insérer <b>des lignes vides</b></p>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="container">
            <section id="zones" class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
                    <label for="AG">Groupe d'annonce</label>
                    <br/><small>Variable {{AG}} </small>
                    <br />
                    <textarea id="AG"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                    <label for="D1">Texte alternatif 1</label>
                    <br/><small>Variable {{D1}} </small>
                    <br />
                    <textarea id="D1"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                    <label for="D2">Texte alternatif 2</label>
                    <br/><small>Variable {{D2}} </small>
                    <br />
                    <textarea id="D2"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                    <label for="URLDIS">Url Display</label>
                    <br/><small>Variable {{URLDIS}} </small>
                    <br />
                    <textarea id="URLDIS"></textarea>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
                    <label for="URLDES">Url de Destination</label>
                    <br/><small>Variable {{URLDES}} </small>
                    <br />
                    <textarea id="URLDES"></textarea>

                </div>
            </section>

            <hr />
            <section>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h2>Seconde étape : Ajoutez vos propres variables</h2>
                            <small>Rajoutez vos textes personnalisés et utilisez les variables <b>{{VAR0}}</b>,<b>{{VAR1}}</b>, etc. pour les insérer dans les variation de vos textes d'annonce. </small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <br/>
            <section id="vars">
                <a id="addVar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign green" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ajouter une variable</a>
                <div class="row">
                    <form class="navbar-form">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <label for="VAR0">{{VAR0}}</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <input type="text" id="VAR0" class="var" style="width: 350px;"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            0
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <form class="navbar-form">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <label for="VAR1">{{VAR1}}</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <input type="text" id="VAR1" class="var" style="width: 350px;"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            0
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>

            <hr />
            <section>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h2>Troisième étape : Créez vos modèles de textes d'annonce</h2>
                            <small>Utilisez du texte ou une variable disponible pour construire chacune des variations d'un texte d'annonce.</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <br/>
            <section id="groups">
                <a id="addGroup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign green" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ajouter une variation d'annonce</a>
                <br/>
                <section class="group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="navbar-form">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <label for="titre">Titre</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <input type="text"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="navbar-form">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <label for="desc1">Description 1</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <input type="text"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="navbar-form">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <label for="desc1">Description 2</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <input type="text"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="navbar-form">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <label for="desc1">Url Display</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <input type="text"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="navbar-form">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <label for="desc1">Url Finale</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <input type="text"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                </section>
            </section>
            <div class="buttons">
                <a href="#" rel="tooltip" id="make" class="btn btn-middle" style="outline: none;" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" data-content="cliquer dans la zone de texte, CTRL+C ou CMD+C pour copier." data-html="true">
                    <span class="gradient">Générer Rapport</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- <span class="pull-right">cliquer dans la zone de texte, CTRL+C ou CMD+C pour copier</span> -->
            <!-- <button class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-s"><a class="white" id="copy-button">Copier !</a></button> -->
            <textarea onclick="this.select();" id="report" cols="160" rows="10" class="bg-grey"></textarea>


        </div>

        <div id="templates" class="hidden">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="navbar-form">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label for="var1">{{var1}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <input type="text" id="var1" class="var" style="width: 350px;"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        0
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <hr/>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">

                        <div class="row margin-top-50"><a href="http://link-tags.com"><img src="assets/images/Logo149-40.png" alt="logo Link-tags"></a></div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <hr/>
                        <div class="row">Tout droits Réservés à <a href="https://twitter.com/notcedricD">@notcedricD</a> 
                        </div>
                        <hr/>
                        <div class="row">Réalisé avec l'aide de <a href="https://twitter.com/sugatasei">@Sugatasei</a>
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="alert alert-success text-center">Je partage</div>
                        <div>
                            <a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=G%C3%A9n%C3%A9rer+vos+annonces+%23AdWords+en+masse+en+quelques+clics+sur+http%3A%2F%2Flink-tags.com%2Fadgen%2Findex.html+via+%40notcedricD" title="Partager sur Twitter" target="_blank" class="btn btn-middle"><span class="fa fa-twitter"> Twitter</span></a>
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Flink-tags.com%2Fadgen%2F" title="Partager sur Facebook" target="_blank" class="btn btn-middle"><span class="fa fa-facebook"> Facebook</span></a>
                            <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Flink-tags.com%2Fadgen%2F" title="Partager sur Google+" target="_blank" class="btn btn-middle"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"> Google+</span></a>
                            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&title=Mass+Adtext+Generator&url=http%3A%2F%2Flink-tags.com%2Fadgen%2F" title="Partager sur LinkedIn" target="_blank" class="btn btn-middle"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"> LinkedIn</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 widget-container widget-profile boxed">
                        <div class="inner clearfix">
                            <div class="avatar"><img src="assets/images/cedric-duma.jpg" alt=""></div>
                            <h5>Cédric Duma</h5>
                            <span class="subtitle">Consultant SEA</span>
                            <div class="follow">
                                <a href="https://twitter.com/notcedricD" class="btn btn-follow" style="outline: none;"><span class="gradient">Suivez-moi</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
        <script>
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
i[r] = i[r] || function () {
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
}, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
a.async = 1;
a.src = g;
m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-31710454-3', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

        </script>
        <script>
            $('[rel=tooltip]').popover({html: true});
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code please?

Comment: The code is pasted into the initial post :)

Comment: Its look like the the procees cant be executed a second time if we modify the var to be parsed and we delete the result into the textarea.

Comment: It's because you're using `append()` on the `textarea`, try setting the value using `val()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jan , i changed to val(), then columns titles dont appear anymore

Comment: And if do that, when i will modify data it will not work if i choose to add a seconde variation of textads

Comment: I think i will simply disable the modification on the textarea. It will be easiest. I huess if i add a clear button the problem will still occur.

Comment: `$('#report').val($('#report').val() + "my new val here");` to set, `$('#report').val("");` to empty

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery .append not appending to textarea after text edited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722914/jquery-append-not-appending-to-textarea-after-text-edited)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
$('#report').append("wathever")
```

You use the append method with a textarea and this is a mistake, use instead val method

```
$('#report').val("wathever")
```

Finally, use instead

```
    /**
 * Build the report
 */
$('#make').on('click', function () {

// Variables dynamiques
    var zones = {};
    var nRows = null;
    var isValid = true;
    $('#zones textarea').each(function () {
        var ary = $(this).val().split("\n");
        zones[$(this).attr('id')] = ary;
        if (nRows === null) {
            nRows = ary.length;
        }
        else if (ary.length !== nRows) {
            isValid = false;
            return;
        }
    });
    if (!isValid) {
       alert('Chaque zone de texte doit contenir le même nombre de lignes (vides ou non vides).');


        return;
    }

// Variables fixes
    var data = {};
    $('#vars input').each(function () {
        data[$(this).attr('id')] = $.trim($(this).val());
    });
    // Clear report
    //edited by jorgesuarezch
    $('#report').val("");
    // Columns name
    var titles = [];
    $('#groups .group:first label').each(function () {
        titles.push($(this).text());
    });
    //edited by jorgesuarezch
    $('#report').val(ary2csv(titles));
    // On boucle sur le nombre de ligne dans les zones
    for (var i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {

// On ajoute a data chaque zone pour la ligne i
        for (var j in zones) {
            data[j] = zones[j][i];
        }

// On parse chaque texte
        $('#groups .group').each(function () {
            var cols = [];
            $(this).find('input').each(function () {
                cols.push(parseStr($(this).val(), data));
            });
            //edited by jorgesuarezch
            $('#report').val( $('#report').val() + ary2csv(cols));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: If you're gonna post my comment as an answer, at least explain why it doesn't work

Comment: I apologize for any inconvenience caused. I hadn't seen the reviews.