# jQuery Can't append text to html after deleting input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form where you can append emoji's to via markdown or clicking in an emoji-picker. When clicked on an emoji in the picker it runs the following jQuery code:

```
$('.emoji-container').click(function () {
   var target = $(this).closest('.emoji-container');
   var emojiName = target.data('clipboard');

   var activityLength = $('.input-field').val().length;
   var emojiLength = (emojiName).length;
   var totalLength = activityLength + emojiLength;

   if (totalLength < 90) {
     $('.clipboard-emoji').html("Added: '" + emojiName + "'");
     $('.input-field').append(emojiName + " ");
      console.log(activityLength, '+', emojiLength, '=', totalLength)
   } else {
     $('.clipboard-emoji').html("Max. characters reached, can't copy");
     console.log('full')
   }
});
```

So everyone is working perfect but when I delete characters in the input field so there is enough again to add another emoji it doesn't append it to the input field. My emoji's are added as markdown like this: `:smiley:`

My console:

```
0 "+" 19 "=" 19   // at this point I add the first emoji
20 "+" 19 "=" 39
40 "+" 19 "=" 59
60 "+" 19 "=" 79
full              // at this point the max is reached and I clear the input again
0 "+" 19 "=" 19   // at this point I cleared the whole input field
0 "+" 10 "=" 10   // as you can see the input length stays 0
0 "+" 11 "=" 11
0 "+" 7 "=" 7
0 "+" 8 "=" 8
```

I can't figure out why it won't add them again when deleting characters or the whole input in the input field

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hL6gye4f/)

Comment: create a fiddle so that we can check and rectify

Comment: how do you clear $('.input-field')?

Comment: @techLove Backspace :p

Comment: Try using `$('.emoji-container').on('input', function () { }` instead of a click event, that may solve it. To echo alive, could you make a fiddle for your problem so we can help please?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Added

Comment: @JayGould Added

Comment: it's showing loading....  only

Comment: @AlivetoDie could you please retry, it's working for me

Comment: @EgonMeijers  sorry but it's not working for me

Comment: @AlivetoDie if it doesn't work please click the options button in the html container and change haml to none, save and close and back :)

Comment: @AlivetoDie Changed it to a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line

```
$('.input-field').append(emojiName + " ");
```

to

```
$('.input-field').val($('.input-field').val() + emojiName + ' ');
```

Apparently `append` is not suited for this operation, but `val()` is. I don't exactly know why, but hey, it works!

**Edit:**
If you want to increase your performance, store the selectors in a variable:

`var $inputField = $('.input-field')`

**Edit 2:**

> $(textarea).append(txt) doesn't work like you [directed at the poster of that question] think. When a page is loaded the text nodes inside the textarea are set the value of that form field. After that, the text nodes and the value can be disconnected. As you type in the field, the value changes, but the text nodes inside it on the DOM do not. Then you change the text nodes with the append() and the browser erases the value because it knows the text nodes inside the tag have changed.
>
> So you want to set the value, you don't want to append. Use jQuery's val() method for this.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722914/jquery-append-not-appending-to-textarea-after-text-edited)

Comment: This works indeed, still need to figure out why. If I figure out why I will edit your answer :)

Comment: @EgonMeijers: Apparently [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722914/jquery-append-not-appending-to-textarea-after-text-edited) is what you were looking for. The accepted answer also has an explanation about why this doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much